# data from NOAA Magnetic Field Calculators (IGRF) for multiples longitude and latitude spacing

Tags: data-request, geospatial, research, noaa

I would like to retrieve data from NOAA Magnetic Field Calculators ([IGRF](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/IAGA/vmod/igrf.html)) for multiple locations by using longitude and latitude grid spacing; say every 5 degree latitude and every 10 degree longitude for the entire globe. Please can advise?

Answer (score 1):

There are several web applications the can calculate IRGF from latitude / longitude coordinates

- http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag-web/?model=igrf
- http://www.geomag.bgs.ac.uk/data_service/models_compass/igrf_form.shtml
- http://wdc.kugi.kyoto-u.ac.jp/igrf/point/index.html

These sites are documented in the **IGRF-12 online data products** section of [this paper](https://earth-planets-space.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40623-015-0228-9):

> Thébault, Erwan, Christopher C. Finlay, Ciarán D. Beggan, Patrick Alken, Julien Aubert, Olivier Barrois, Francois Bertrand et al. "International geomagnetic reference field: the 12th generation." Earth, Planets and Space 67, no. 1 (2015): 79.

Note that the same section also lists C and Fortran code that could be used in a programmatic solution.